# Match the values in dict

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have a dict data:

`dic={'apple': {'eat': ['jack', 'rose']}}`

I am using the code:

`print('jack' not in dic['apple'].values())`

but the result is True , I hope it will be False

after i changing the dict into:

```
dic1={'apple': {'eat': {'jack': {}, 'rose': {}}}
dic2={'apple': [('eat', 'jack'), ('eat', 'rose')]}
```

and code `print('jack' not in list(dic['apple'].values()))`

all of them doesn`t work.
how I can get the result False?

Comment: Do you mean `print('jack' not in dic['apple']['eat'])` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
dic['apple'].values()
```

is a list of all the dictionary values. Your only value in the nested dict is

```
['jack', 'rose']
```

so `values()` will return

```
[['jack', 'rose']]
```

Thus

```
'jack' not in [['jack', 'rose']]
```

is `True`

Comment: so how i can turn [['jack', 'rose']] to ['jack', 'rose'] ? That will solve my problem.